# Wordpress: How to get the Header Image ID

Tags: php, wordpress

**Short story:** 
I'm trying to get the ID of the Header Image in Wordpress.

All I found was this guide, which dosn't seem to work anymore:http://nickohrn.com/2013/09/get-attachment-id-wordpress-header-image/

**Long Story**
I'm trying to make the WP Header responsive with an srcset. so I don't want to use this code

```
<img id="masthead-bg" src="<?php header_image() ?>" alt="">
```

...but instead want to use the wp_get_attachment_image_srcset function to get the srcset of my header image. Only problem: I need an Image ID for this function -> The ID of my Header image.

```
<img id="masthead-bg" 
src="<?php header_image() ?>" 
srcset="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_srcset( image_id(), 'thumbnail' ); ?>" 
sizes="100vw" alt="">
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
    // Get the header image data    
    $data = get_object_vars(get_theme_mod('header_image_data'));

    // Now check to see if there is an id    
    $attachment_id = is_array($data) && isset($data['attachment_id']) ? $data['attachment_id'] : false;

    if($attachment_id) {
       // Put your image code here, user whatever function to get image by id you need
    }
```

Note: if you use a proper WordPress function to get the image it should add in all the srcset etc stuff for you, to allow for responsive images.

Comment: Hi Simon! This seems to be the code from my link above... which didn't work for me, because it returned no value. `$attachment_id` is empty even though a custom header image is set... not sure why.

The Wordpress function to get the Header image is `<?php header_image() ?>`which only gives me a single URL. Or am I missing a function to display a custom header?

Seems like WP forgot to make those responsive....

Comment: Hmm that is very odd if that returns nothing. Does $data contain anything or is that null as well. Totally agree if header_image() is not returning a responsive image that is a bit odd.

Comment: Crazy.. when I just display the whole `$data` array it shows me `attachment_id = 245`(or whatever header image I set). So the $data array has the correct information... but the second line of code seems to mess something up.

Comment: Ahh it could be $data is an object and not an array... try `var_dump($data->attachment_id);` and see what you get

Comment: You are right, thank you sir! This new first line fixes the problem...

`$data = get_object_vars(get_theme_mod('header_image_data'));`

Comment: I used this extracted header attachement ID to get an srcset of the header image, which dind't work. Details are described in this separate post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37707601/wordpress-add-responsive-srcset-header-image-to-theme

Comment: One more addition: In the backend $data will return an array, in the frontend $data will return an array. Not sure why... but this should finally fix it:
`$data = get_theme_mod('header_image_data');
$data = is_object($data) ? get_object_vars($data) : $data;`
Maby you can update the answer?

Answer (score 1):

To answer the original question, I've found the simplest way to get the ID while I was filtering the markup that gets outputted by `<?php the_header_image_tag(); ?>` (introduced in v4.4).

```
function header_img_markup( $html, $header, $attr) {

    // we can get the image ID by passing its src url to this method
    $header_img_id = attachment_url_to_postid($attr['src']);

    // now we can get its metadata from the db
    $header_img_data = wp_get_attachment_metadata($header_img_id);

    // now we can use the data
    $customSizeWidth = $header_img_data['sizes']['my-custom-size']['width'];

    // ...your custom output here...
    return $html;
}
add_filter('get_header_image_tag', 'header_img_markup', 20, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Responsive Wordpress Header Image with fallback:

```
if (get_header_image() !== '') {
    $attachment_id = attachment_url_to_postid(get_header_image());
    echo wp_get_attachment_image($attachment_id, 'large');
} 
if (get_header_image() == '') {
    echo '<h1>'.get_bloginfo( "name" ).'</h1>';
    echo '<h2>'.get_bloginfo( "description" ).'</h2>';
}
```